# Each product color attribute in a seperate div on shop page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i have searched everywhere for this without any luck whatsoever.

What i found is how to show product color attributes seperated by a commma on product page in woocommerce.

But i want to have each color be in a different div so i can style them differently based on color.

What i got so far:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_color_attribute', 5 );
function display_color_attribute() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_color';
        echo '<span class="attribute-color">' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>';
    }
}
```

This will add a span class saying "1st color, 2nd color".
However how can i make the colors be seperated like this:

```
<div class="colour-swatch interactive js-product-colour-swatch">                                                                                        

<div class="swatch" data-value="(show color attribute)">
    <div class="circle">
        <div style="background-color: var(--show color attribute);"></div>
        <a href="https://example.com/?attribute_pa_color=(show color attribute)"></a>
    </div>                                              
</div>

<div class="swatch" data-value="(show color attribute)">
    <div class="circle">
        <div style="background-color: var(--show color attribute);"></div>
        <a href="https://example.com/?attribute_pa_color=(show color attribute)"></a>
    </div>
</div>                                                                  


</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!